# Application or web service to upload caption files at the same time as I upload videos to Youtube?

Tags: youtube, web-services

I have 100 .mp4 video files that I want to upload to YouTube. For each .mp4 files I have a .srt file ([caption file](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734698)) with the same file name. I'm looking for an application or web service that can:

- upload all videos *and* caption files at once? We can upload several videos by drag and drop, but I wonder if there is any similar bulk upload for caption files. Note that I don't want to merge each MP4+SRT into one MP4 before uploading, but instead I want to upload both the MP4 and the SRT to Youtube as the latter [supports SRT caption file](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734698).

And if possible:

- works on Windows 7
- free

[image]

Comment: You might want to explain that YouTube accepts SRT files, I was not aware of it and was thinking your question was about merging MP4+SRT→MP4 before uploading :-)